# MySQL select inside select inside select

Tags: mysql, select, nested, parent, children

What i want to have are all parentid numbers that are children from multiple other parents which are also children from one other parent. All rows are inside the same table.

Now what i have so far is this (and it works):

```
SELECT * 
FROM location 
WHERE parentid IN (
    SELECT id 
    FROM location 
    WHERE parentid IN (
        SELECT id 
        FROM location 
        WHERE parentid = 0
    )
)
```

The only thing i'm wondering about is, would there be any better/faster way to achieve the exact same thing? The table consists of about 200.000 rows.

Comment: You could do a self-join.  `SELECT * FROM location a INNER JOIN location b ON b.parentid = a.parentid ....`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want the grandchildren of `parentid = 0`.  Personally, I think explicit 
joins are easier to follow and likely to produce a better execution plan:

```
select l2.*
from location l join
     location l1
     on l1.parentid = l.parentid join
     location l2
     on l2.parentid = l1.id
where l.parentid = 0;
```

The only caveat:  Perhaps the `where` statement should be `where l.id = 0`.  In this case you can actually simplify the query to:

```
select l2.*
from location l1
     location l2
     on l2.parentid = l1.id
where l1.parentid = 0;
```